# Seeing a significant delay on first typing event fired to event handler in React/redux with debounce

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

My end goal is to have a search filter box that makes an API call to update a `ListView` items.  When the user starts typing, I want to immediately dispatch an event to show a loader on top of the `ListView` items, and in real time have the text in the search filter update using component state (I think). Then I want to have a debounced dispatch that makes the API call, updates items and state in the store.

Here's the basics of my search component:

```
class Filters extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      search: this.props.filters.search,
    }

    this.onSearchChange = this.onSearchChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSearchDebounced = _.debounce(function() {
      console.log('handleSearchDebounced')
      // this.props.onSearchFilterChange.apply(this, [this.state.search])
    }, 250)
  }
  onSearchChange(e) {
    console.log('onSearchChange')
    this.setState({ search: e.target.value })
    // simple dispatch that shows the loader
    this.props.startLoading()
    this.handleSearchDebounced()
  }
  render() {
    const {
      filters,
      onSearchFilterChange,
    } = this.props
    console.log('filters is re-rendering')
    return (
      <FiltersContainer>
        <input
          placeholder="Search"
          value={this.state.search}
          onChange={this.onSearchChange}
        />
      </FiltersContainer>
    )
  }
}
```

Here's the problem, the first time I type into the search box I get about 2 seconds of lag when I can't interact with the screen, even with no API call, etc.  If I remove the `dispatch` to show the loader, than it updates fine. Also the interesting thing is that each subsequent typing to the search box WORKS FINE after the first laggy one (with the `dispatch`).The debouncing appears to be working correctly from my console logs.

I'm also attaching the profiler which shows the huge difference between the first and subsequent typing events.

Any ideas on this one?

[image: Profile]

Comment: maybe the problem is within another component (where you show the loader)?

Comment: Yeah I will expand this out higher up the hierarchy if no one can spot something here.  Since the hangup appears to be with the event handler I didn't want to bloat this right away.

Comment: Yes it is in fact related to something going on in other components, investigating that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I discovered the issue was related to `React.PureComponent`. Simply enough I had just a bare couple functions defined in render in different components to compute values. Easy fix, DON'T do that.  Also, it turned out that rendering tooltips in my list view had a huge performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing your code I noticed a bug. You are updating the state mutably, instead you should update the state immutably.

You are directly setting this.props.filters.search in the state which is the wrong way and it may cause issues. You should update it in the componentDidMount lifecycle hook, for example.

```
this.state = {
  search: '',
}
componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({ search: this.props.filters.search });
}
```